# Can't use TimeSpanDisplay in app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm a novice of Windows phone 7 developer.
I try this tutorial to create an stopwatch app. http://windowsphone7developerguide.blograby.com/stopwatch/

But, I get this error when typing this line

```
<local:TimeSpanDisplay x:Name=”TotalTimeDisplay” Grid.Row=”3”
Grid.ColumnSpan=”2” DigitWidth=”67”
HorizontalAlignment=”Center”
FontFamily=”Segoe WP Black” FontSize=”108” />

Error   1   The type 'local:TimeSpanDisplay' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   D:\New CS Job\Window Phone 7 Dev\Project\Stopwatch\Stopwatch\MainPage.xaml  35  10  Stopwatch
```

I try to search my error in google but it seem nothing useful for me. Please help me, I feel so depressed. Thanks!

Comment: If you read through the tutorial you will find the heading "The TimeSpanDisplay User Control" near the bottom, the text below shows how to create the user control you are missing.

Comment: oh, thanks for your help! I'm too silly :)